# Wronski - ordinary second order linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two solution that are linearly independent of the equation:
$$(P(x) y')' + q(x) y = 0$$ 
on $[a,b]$, with $P(x) >0$.

1. How we prove that $y_1$ and $y_2$ do not vanish simultaneously?
2. How we prove that, if $y_1$ and $y_2$ aren't $0$, and are linearly dependent, then they are vanish simultaneously?

Comment: Your ODE is in self-adjoint form; does that help you at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this without wronskians if you recall that $(py')' + qy = 0$ has unique solution. we can use the uniqueness of solutions, in fact a simpler version which says that $y_1(a) = 0,$ then $y_1 = 0,$ to show that if two solutions $y_1, y_2$  are such that $y_1(a) = y_2(a),$  then $y_1(x) = k y_2(x)$ for all $x.$ that proves your first claim.

i am not clear what your trying to say in (2)

$\bf edit:$
you don't need to know that $y_1$ and $y_2$  are solutions of the differential equation. if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly dependent, then that means one is a multiple of the other. so if $y_1(a) = 0$ that implies $y_2(a) = 0.$ we have already seen that $y_1(a) = 0$ implies $y_1(x) = 0$ and in the same way $y_2(x) = 0$ for all $x.$

Comment: But how about the question 2, please?

Answer (score 1):

Your differential equation for the Wronski determinant is

$$\frac d{dt}\ln(\det(W(t)))=\frac d{dt}\ln(P(t))$$

and thus has the solution

$$W(t)=W(t_0)\frac{P(t)}{P(t_0)}$$

which connects the linear dependence in one point to the linear dependence on the whole domain.

---

1. If $y_1 $ and $y_2$ have a common zero in $t^*$, then $\det(W(t^*))=0$ and thus $\det(W(t))=0$ for all $t$.
2. This is wrong. They need not have any zero. However, if w.l.o.g. $y_1(t^*)=0=\det(W(t^*))$ then either $y_1$ is the zero solution or $y_2(t^*)=0$.

Comment: Please, but what's the answer of the two questions? It's the same ansmer for both. No?